# Core 3.x LINQ -> DateTime and string comparison error

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote the code as below.

```
purchaseList = (from tp in context.TbPurchasebill
                            where
                              tp.CompanyNo == companyNo &&
                              tp.BillDate.ToString("yyyy-MM").Contains(billDate) &&
                              tp.DeleteTf == false
                            orderby
                              tp.BusinessName
                            select new PurchaseList
                            {
                                BillNo = tp.BillNo,
                                BillDate = tp.BillDate,
                                BusinessName = tp.BusinessName,
                                GoodsName = tp.GoodsName
                            }).ToList();
```

tp.BillDate.ToString("yyyy-MM").In Contents (billDate), BillDate is in DateTime format and billDate is a string of values "2021-05".

Executing the code will cause the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
> 'DbSet
> .Where(t => t.CompanyNo == __companyNo_0 && (Nullable)t.BillDate != null &&
> t.BillDate.ToString("yyyy-MM").Contains(__billDate_1) && t.DeleteTf ==
> (Nullable)False)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the
> query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
> explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
> AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.g__CheckTranslated|8_0(ShapedQueryExpression
> translated, <>c__DisplayClass8_0& )    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression
> query)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression
> query, Boolean async)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase
> database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object
> cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
> AccountManagerData.Repository.GetPurchaseList(Int32 companyNo, String
> billDate) in
> C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\AccountManager\AccountManagerData\Repository.cs:line
> 3573    at
> AccountManager.Controllers.Bill.PurchaseController.GetPurchaseList(PurchaseForListFind
> purchase) in
> C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\AccountManager\AccountManager\Controllers\Bill\PurchaseController.cs:line
> 30    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
> target, Object[] parameters)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
>
> ---
>
> To fix the error, you can run 'AsEnumerable()' at the end and call
> 'Where' one more time.

Is there any other way but to do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with that `billDate` property. Compare months, years? Can you please give some examples of values in `billDate` property?

Comment: They only want to calculate data corresponding to the year and month of a particular date. '2021-05-21 19:23:45' -> '2020-05'(billDate)

Comment: EF is not very good with dates... it has never been

Comment: Is BillDate a string in DateTime format or is BillDate of type DateTime?  If the former then try `DateTime.Parse(tp.BillDate).ToString("yyyy-MM")`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to replace

```
tp.BillDate.ToString("yyyy-MM").Contains(billDate) &&
```

with

```
tp.BillDate.ToString("yyyy-MM") == billDate &&
```

Comment: The method has already been tried, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much to solve.

I just decided to do the following.

int year = billDate.split('-')[0];
int month = billDate.split('-')[1];

tp.BillDate.Year == year && tp.BillDate.Month == month;

Comment: That code doesn't work. `billDate.Split[0]` is a string not an int.  If you meant it to be a string then @Oliver gave the answer.